# csharp schedule email razor mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I can do this easily in php/mysql, however, c# mvc razor is a whole different story.

All i want to do is set a cron job on the server (i presumed it is not a cron job for c# mvc, don't even know what is called) so that an email can be send based on months: 1mth, 2mths, etc

Below is my sendEmail, which doesn't work due to the fact that i need to include username/password in the code so that it can work, which in my opinion is absurd (sendemail in "php" doesn't require senders credentials) unless there is a better way, please show me the way.

```
//send email
public void sendEmail()
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("toemail@domain.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("toemail@domain.com"));
            message.Subject = "This is my subject";
            message.Body = "testing testing testing";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "localhost";
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Send(message);
        }

//date difference
public decimal monthDifference(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
        {
            if (d1 > d2)
            {
                DateTime hold = d1;
                d1 = d2;
                d2 = hold;
            }

            decimal monthsApart = Math.Abs((12 * (d1.Year - d2.Year)) + d2.Month - d1.Month - 1);
            decimal daysinStartingMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d1.Year, d1.Month);
            monthsApart = monthsApart + (1 - ((d1.Day - 1) / daysinStartingMonth));

            decimal daysinEndingMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d2.Year, d2.Month);
            monthsApart = monthsApart + (d2.Day / daysinEndingMonth);
            return monthsApart;
        }

//i will use linq to query the database and get the start and end date
if(monthDifference(start, end) == 2 || monthDifference(start, end) == 1)
{
sendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send email at scheduled, you should create a Console application and use the Windows Task Scheduler to run the application when you need.
If you can't use the Windows Task Scheduler, you can use library like [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net)

You can configure your smtp server using the `web.config` / `app.config` file : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `SmtpClient` object which uses, you guess it, SMTP.

In PHP/MySQL you often use `sendmail` which is able to send emails from the server without being an SMTP server.

Windows does not contain this functionality and you will always have to use some sort of mail relay provider to send emails to the world.

If you don't want to store username/passwords then configure your SMTP server that it allows anonymous connections from certain IP's or hostnames.

Or you can store the SMTP login credentials in your `app.config`.